# Is element displayed in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the element is displayed in the div(`divContent`) or not.

The starting point is: elements: 1,2,3,4 are displayed.

So why the function: checkIfInView, returns true for element number 6?

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/2971/

```
function checkIfInView(element){
    var offset = element.offset().top - $('#divContent').scrollTop();

    if(offset > $('#divContent').innerHeight){
        // Not in view
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling `innerHeight`.  You need the parenthesis for it to execute the function.  Otherwise you are evaluating against the function declaration (not sure if that's the right term for it.  Correct me if I'm wrong please).

Change

```
if(offset > $('#divContent').innerHeight){
```

to

```
if(offset > $('#divContent').innerHeight()){
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work..
$('#divContent').scrollTop(100);
    var el = $('#divContent').children().eq(0);
    alert(checkIfInView(el));
    var el = $('#divContent').children().eq(6);
    alert(checkIfInView(el));

in both cases it should be false..

Comment: @AlonShmiel That's just because your logic is bad.  I've created a new script: http://jsfiddle.net/sj0aeavw/1.  For starters, you should be using a relatively positioned parent, you should be using `position` instead of `offset` (one pertains to the parent element and the other pertains to the entire document), and you should be checking the position against both the top and the bottom of the container.